# Create plain box window like this in Swift?

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

Below is a screenshot of the 'Squish' app on the App Store. How am I able to make a window like that, with rounded corners and no separator between the titlebar and content?

The only difference is I want to have a title on the title bar.

So in short, how do make a window like in the image but with a title?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new NSWindow in Xcode, then create an outlet for it, and set the `titlebarAppearsTransparent` property to `true`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var windowBlank: NSWindow!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    windowBlank.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    windowBlank.backgroundColor = NSColor.whiteColor()
}
```

You also have to enable the `Full size content view` checkbox in the `Attributes inspector`.

[image]