# Create a fixed position window in Mac Application development

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nswindow

I'm new in Mac Application development. I want to create a small tool which having a small window fixed position at the right bottom of the screen like this picture:

[image]

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible - but I wouldn't recommend it, as it could be a bad user experience.

The solution is simple, though: set the `.isMovable` property of the window to `false`.

For example, for a `window` IBOutlet, setting:

```
window.isMovable = false
```

in `applicationDidFinishLaunching` works well.

You can also, for example, use `window.setFrameOrigin(_ point: NSPoint)` to first set it at a fixed position.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. That helps me. One more question, can I hide/remove the three buttons (Red, Orange and Green) on the left top of the window? I just want to close the app by pressing a hot key.

Comment: You're welcome. Start with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32209482/2227743) then also uncheck the "Close", "Minimize" and "Resize" boxes in the "Controls" section of Xcode's panel.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much.